# NSThreads in Automatic Reference Counting(ARC)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsthread, nsautoreleasepool, automatic-ref-counting

i am trying to use NSThreads with ARC in 4.3.5. With iOS 5 everything works perfect, but if i try it on a older iOS like 4.3 its leaking. Normally i would use a Autoreleasepool for NSThreads but since there is no manual Autoreleasepool in ARC i don't know how to fix this.

I get loads of Messages like "__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4567b40 of class NSComparisonPredicate autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking" in my Console after i start a Thread.

```
NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(showAlert) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

How to correctly thread with ARC and iOS prior to 5.0.

Cheers
nettz

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
-(void)showAlert
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // Your code.
    }
}
```

Comment: And by "// Your code." he means the code in the selector, in this case "showAlert". Took me a minute to parse that.

Comment: I've edited the code snippet for clarity. Ben's comment referred to Jonathan's old version, without the surrounding "showAlert" stuff. :)