# How to pass string to handling main thread operation function

Tags: iphone, ios

Hi i want to pass string to updateProgressBar function in my code to display some data. so how i can do it

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

and my function look like this

```
-(void)updateProgressBar
{
    lbl.text = ?    
}
```

Comment: you can pass in withObject, instead of passing nil, pass your string

Comment: @Veer and how to receive in function

Comment: Make it global, and use in function,

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to pass argument on your updateProgressBar.

You can do like this

```
    NSString * alpha;

   //assign some value to alpha

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar:) withObject:alpha waitUntilDone:NO];

    -(void)updateProgressBar:(NSString *)beta
     {
          lbl.text = beta;    
     }
```

OR you can also pass multiple arguments using performSelectorOnMainThread.
you can search on google many tutorials are present about this.

Comment: but i m getting following warning when doing through your suggested way __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x55f3ec0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Comment: try to use this answer, see below

Comment: The function performSelectorOnMainThread is used when you want to come back on main thread from any background thread or a new thread then you should use that selectorOnMainThread. otherwise you should be using simple performSelector or just [self yourfunctionName]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) to avoid writing a separate method:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    lbl.text = newLabel;
});
```

---

To address the issue described in the comments on this answer (`__NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x55f3ec0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place`):

You are most likely executing this snippet in a background thread without an autorelease pool.  You can either [create one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350174/how-to-set-up-an-autorelease-pool-when-using-nsthread-detachnewthreadselectort) or avoid using `autorelease`.

Comment: This snippet is correct.  Your code, which incorporates this snippet, might leak.  However, I would have to see that code to tell you why it is leaking.

Comment: because i m getting this warning  __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x55f3ec0 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking when calling this only

Comment: - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    //[imageArray addObject:string];}
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ll.text = string;
    });

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  Also, try running the static analyzer.

Comment: Yes working fine no more leaks and can you also tell is there is another option for background process? anyway thanks a lot