# iOS: symbol not found _ojbc_loadweakretained while switched target to ios 4.3 (arc)

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

At the beginning we built our iOS app targeting 5.0+ and used ARC to simply memory management. Later for backward compatibility, we decided to support iOS 4.3. Then I just

1. Installed iOS 4.3 simulator
2. Modified app deployment target to 4.3
3. Clean, build, run

But the app quit unexpectly with following output

> dyld: Symbol not found: _objc_loadWeakRetained
>
> Referenced from: /Users/xxx/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/16E98912-33B5-4660-A9A3-879D92735E44/myApp.app/myApp
>
> Expected in: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation

I knew 4.3 didn't support weak reference, but it's weird that compiler never complained at compiling time, it simply crashed at runtime.

**UPDATED:**
I used **unsafe_unretained** instead of weak keyword, the app ran anyway. But I got lots of warnings like

> __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x564bd90 of class __NSArrayM autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking"* '

Was it normal? How to eliminate these warnings?

Comment: check your baseSDk it would be 5.0.

Comment: My baseSDK was 5.1, should I change it to 4.3? I can't find 4.3 sdk in the list

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be interesting to see if you change the deployment target back to 5.1 if the problem goes away. My guess is it will not.

The only ways I know of to get this kind of error are:

1) is to create a concurrent NSOperation, then not provide a runloop/autorelease pool for it
2) do not create an autorelease pool in main.m
3) create a NSThread using an object that , then try to message an object on that thread without having created an autorelease pool

Assuming the problem is most likely 3), you can find out how to create a pool for the thread in this [past discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350174/how-to-set-up-an-autorelease-pool-when-using-nsthread-detachnewthreadselectort)